# Rectangle Class that "has-a" Point class member data. Member data will not update when using Point class's member functions

Tags: c++, class, object, get, member

Noobie here playing around! I created a Rectangle class that has two member variables :
Point ur      and      Point ll (ur is Upper Right and ll is Lower Left points of the rectangle). Point is a class on its own with member variables Fraction X and Fraction Y. Fraction is a class with member variables num and denom. All of these variables are protected within their corresponding classes.

Creating the Rectangle objects are simple enough, but once I try to move these points using a member function within the Point class, the Rectangle Object's X and Y values do not get updated, but the values inside the function are updated.

Here is the header file for the Rectangle Class :

```
   class Rectangle {
   public:
     Rectangle () : ur(), ll() {
     }
     ~Rectangle () {
     }
     Rectangle (const Rectangle *);
     Rectangle (const Point&, const Point&);
     Rectangle & operator=(const Rectangle &);

     Rectangle compareArea(const Rectangle *) const;
     Rectangle compareVolume(const Rectangle *) const;

     Point getUR(void) const;
     Point getLL(void) const;

     void print(const Rectangle *) const;

  protected:
    Point ur;
    Point ll;
  };
```

and my Point class:

```
 class Point {
 public:
   Point() : x(), y() {
   }// Default const
   ~Point() {
   }// Destructor
   Point(const Point&); // Copy const
   Point(const Fraction&, const Fraction&);
   Point& operator=(const Point&); // Assignment

   void moveBy(const Fraction&, const Fraction&);
   void moveBy(int);
   void flipByX(void);
   void flipByY(void);
   void flipThroughOrigin(void);
   void print(void);

   Fraction getX(void) const;
   Fraction getY(void) const;

 protected:
   Fraction x; // x-coordinate of the point
   Fraction y; // y-coordinate of the point
 };
```

Here is how one of the "move" member functions of Point class looks like:

```
void Point::moveBy(const Fraction& dx, const Fraction& dy) {

  x += dx; // Overloaded all comparison/ arithmetic operators in basic Fraction class
  y += dy;
}
```

I am required to create the Rectangle object by declaring a Rectangle Pointer that is set at null until the user decides to create two Rectangle objects.

Everything is running fine, and the values that the user enters is stored in correctly.

However, when I try to move the Upper right (Point ur) and lower left (Point ll) points in the Rectangle class with the member functions in Point, the values of Fraction x and Fraction y for Point ur and Point ll are not updated.

Is this because my "get" methods are const?

Here is how I call the "move" methods:

```
Rectangle* r1 = new Rectangle(xC, yC);   // Assume xC and yC are proper fraction                 coordinates for X and Y

// Move now after user chooses some options in a menu

r1->getUR().getX().moveBy(Fraction(xNew, yNew), Fraction(xNew, yNew)); // Assume xNew, yNew are valid Fractions that the user has chosen to move his Points by...
```

The values are not reflected (not updated nor stored). I get the original xC and yC values when I print the coordinate points. What am I doing wrong? (I am required to create my code this way. Cannot use smart pointers, vectors, etc.) If you want to see the rest of my code to determine what it is I am doing wrong, I will post it ASAP.

Comment: Yeah, there's that too.  This isn't Java.  :P  Unless you *need* to decouple the variable's scope from the object's lifetime, stick with actual objects rather than pointers, and take advantage of automatic destruction.  Your life will be a lot easier overall.

Comment: An addition: What is a 'Fraction' - the question is incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your getters - but it does not have to do with them being `const`. (`const`, in practice, means the object is not being modified. Technically, it means the member function can be called on a `const` object and the type of `this` is `const Class*` as opposed to `Class*`.)

The problem is that they return objects:

```
Fraction getX(void) const;
```

That is, brand new objects. *Copies* of the actual members. You want to return references:

```
Fraction& getX();
```

and if you need a const version:

```
const Fraction& getX() const;
```

Comment: In this case he can hardly return const Point& if he would like to change that Point by non-const Point::moveBy().

Comment: @JanKorous good point. I swapped the const and non-const versions, the question-relevant one is at the top now.

Comment: I can't believe I forgot about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since it's returning an object by value rather than by reference or pointer, `getUR()` returns a *copy* of the `Point` within it.  Changes to the copy won't affect the original.

If you want to be able to modify the rectangle's corners that way, you'll need to have it return a reference or pointer.

A safer way, though, would be to have the Rectangle class itself make the needed changes.  That way you keep control of your class's internal details, and the users of this class don't have to be as concerned with pointers/references that could open a wormhole if they're used after the object dies.

Answer (score 0):

There might be more issues:

a. I am not sure if you should't call it like this

```
r1->getUR().moveBy(Fraction(xNew, yNew), Fraction(xNew, yNew));
```

b. The real problem is you are returning by value and not by reference from Rectangle::getUR() so you call moveBy() on totally different object than you would like to. If this is not some stupid error and you don't get it straight away I would suggest reading something about C++ references.